# Optional time plus constant is a Stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

If $T$ is an optional  time and $\theta$ a constant >0, I want to show, that $T+\theta$ is a stopping time regarding the standard filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}_+}$. I have already shown, that $\{T+\theta<t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$, However since it is not given, that $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in\mathbb{R}_+}$ is right continuous, I do not know how to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you notice, we cannot conclude directly using $\{T + \theta < t\}$, since the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is not necessarily right-continuous.
To overcome this issue, you can use the fact that if $T$ is a $(\mathcal{F}_t)$-optional time, then it is a $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})$-stopping time, where $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is the right-continuous limit of $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ (I've included below a definition of $(\mathcal{F_{t+}})_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$; see Corollary 2.4 in [1] for a proof of the implication).

Given $t \in \mathbb{R}^+$, let us now consider
$$\{T + \theta \leq t\} = \{T \leq t - \theta\}.$$
If $t < \theta$ we have that $\{T \leq t - \theta\} = \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}_t$ and we are done. If $t \geq \theta$ then $\{T \leq t-\theta\} \in \mathcal{F}_{(t - \theta)+}$ since $T$ is a $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})$-stopping time and we conclude by observing that $\mathcal{F}_{(t-\theta)+} \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ (this follows directly from the definition below).

**Definition:**
*The right-continuous limit of $(\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_{t+})_{t \in \mathbb{R}+}$ defined by
$$ \mathcal{F}_{t+} = \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} \mathcal{F}_{t+\epsilon} \text{ for every } t \geq 0.$$*
Intuitively: $\mathcal{F}_{t+}$ corresponds to the information which is available *just after* time $t$, while $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information available *at* time $t$.

[1]: I. Karatzas, S. E. Shreve, "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus"